# Concatenate two strings in UITableView's detailedTextLabel

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, sdk

Hi I have this line of code.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"city"];
```

I want to use two objectForKeys. I have a "city" & "state" key I would like them to put together in that detailedTextLabel. How would I do that?

Comment: Im sorry... I really don't understand what it is you are trying to ask

Comment: consider marking the correct answer, so that others can get benefit from this post too. thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
                             [[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"city"], 
                             [[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"state"]];
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you so that people can see it when they later browse for the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
NSString *city = [[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"city"];
NSString *state = [[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"state"];
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", city, state];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = combined;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"city"],[[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"state"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *city = [[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"city"];
NSString *state =[[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"state"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"city is : %@  state is: %@", city, state];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this ?

```
NSString *city = [[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"city"];
NSString *state = [[self->jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"state"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",city,state];
```